# IOS compiler warning "Multiple segues with identifier work"

Tags: ios, cocoa

So i am re-using a view for multiple segues, i have a UITableView, which contains 4 Cells

Work1 - Tag 1
Work2 - Tag 2
Work3 - Tag 3
Work4 - Tag 4

I have tagged each cell accordingly, now, in prepare for segue with identifier, i fetch the tag of the index row selected, and set it in the new next view, which i then segue over to.

In the other View, i intercept the value and set some things in the view accordingly.

For this to work, i need 4 segues with the same identifier, one from each static cell.
(I have the cell actions set up via storyboard)

This leads to this warning, is there any way to get around this?

EDIT: I asume i would have to hook up the segues programmatically, so how would i do this?

Comment: Why don't you just use 4 different segues?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can't have two segues with the same identifier on your Storyboard. And I highly doubt you can do this in code too. So why bother and not use just 1 universal segue that will be called programatically by `[self preformSegueWithidentifier:@""];`?

Comment: Well i can, i do not get a compiler Error, i get a warning

Comment: @JohnDOe then I assume they will be called at the same time.

Comment: You wont get an error because there is at least one segue with that name. Who knows which one it will run or what will get messed up by doing this.

Comment: It does not matter which one it runs, the purpose of it is to preform an action on a UITableCell Click

Comment: @JohnDOe Are you serious?! So why not just have **one** segue for all the cells?

Comment: Fixed it, sorry for the dum question

Comment: I just needed an action for CellSelected in static table, used didSelectedRowAtIndexPath to fire the segue

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you "need 4 segues with the same identifier". And this warning is here for a good reason.

If I tell you "Go talk to Jim". And you know 4 people named Jim, how would you possibly know which Jim I was referring to. The same thing is happening here, you are telling a view controller to use a segue, but it has 4 of them named the same thing, so it has no idea what segue to use. Doing this programmitically will not fix anything.

You only get a warning because the code will work, it will run a segue, but you have no idea of knowing which one it will run.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, this is not the case. Using your example, it's like saying "Go talk to jim", when 4 people can talk to Jim. You can ask each one of them, they all get the same segue: "Talk to jim", and they all go to jim. Why would you want to have "Jack - talk to Jim"AND "Sarah - talk to Jim" etc. ?